# Incorrect order of process.OutputDataReceived and process.ErrorDataReceived events in C#

Tags: c#, process

I'm experiencing an issue with the Process class in C#. I have noticed that the events process.OutputDataReceived and process.ErrorDataReceived are being called in the incorrect order, meaning that the ErrorDataReceived event is triggered before OutputDataReceived, resulting in a mix-up of the output and errors.

Here is how I have set up the event handlers:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "temp.bat";
// Process configuration...

process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Data);
    }
};

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Example temp.bat file:

```
dir
dir1
```

Execution result:

```
D:\>dir
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 6273-2411
 Directory of D:\
01.07.2023 23:12    <DIR>          .
ERROR: "dir1" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
01.07.2023 23:12    <DIR>          ..
ERROR: operable program or batch file.
22.06.2023 01:12    <DIR>          Books
22.06.2023 01:13    <DIR>          Documents
11.06.2023 16:35    <DIR>          Films
...
D:\>dir1
```

How can I fix this issue and ensure the correct order of calling the OutputDataReceived and ErrorDataReceived events? I would like to preserve the original order of the output and errors messages.

Also, empty lines are being consumed.
How can I make the output consistent with the standard Windows command prompt?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Maybe writing to console or a UI is too slow process and the event handlers are congested. In the event handlers try to only put (Enqueue) the data in a ConcurrentQueue **as fast as possible**, and in another thread Dequeue them and process. I used a BackgroundWorker (because in my case this is a Windows Forms application), but a timer or ThreadPool task is also would be a good choice. It solved this problem for me!

```
private ConcurrentQueue<string> lines = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

...

process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    lines.Enqueue(e.Data);
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("ERROR: ");
    sb.Append(e.Data);
    lines.Enqueue(sb.ToString());
};


...

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    string line;
    bool finished = false;
    while (!finished)
    {
        while (lines.TryDequeue(out line))
        {
            finished = procLine(line, worker, e);
            if (finished)
                break;
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    }
}
```

I also put a special echo at the end of the bat file, and when it reaches, the procLine will return true.